tcsh command history does not get recorded after multi-line alias executed
This observation is somewhat bizarre, but should be easy to reproduce.

Start a new tcsh (and ssh login in my case, should not matter)

set history=100; set savehist=1; run some command and check that history is working, that is, that the commands being run are being recorded in the history.

define the multi-line alias


alias echopath 'foreach k (`seq 1 $#path`) \
 echo ${k}: $path[$k] \
end'


Run the echopath alias

now the command history does not get recorded. Output of history ends with the following, and does not get any new commands recorded


    15  8:32    h
    16  8:32    echopath
    17  8:32    echo ${k}: $path[$k]
    18  8:32    end


what on earth is going on here?

